# Trying to float 3 images one underneath the other and float text to the right of them

Tags: css, css-float, floating

I am having trouble putting 3 img's one on top of the other on the left side of my page and floating text to the right. I have been stuck for 2 days now and I have to fix this without changing the HTML.

My CSS is

```
img{
    width: 30%;
    height: 240px;
    border: 3px solid #0066ff;
    margin: 5px;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.right{
    border: 5px solid #00008b;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 375px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/MyTheoryIs/ggw7xy5s/#

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is float the 2 parent divs `.left` & `.right` instead of the content inside of it.

This also eliminates the need to have the images 30% width.

CSS:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.left {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}    
.right{
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(40% - 20px);
    float: right;
}
```

NOTE: Using floats overwrites the display property (unless you are using display:flex)

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ggw7xy5s/3/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are after a solution like this:

```css
.left, .right{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left{
  width: 30%;
  border: 3px solid #0066ff;
  margin-right: 1%;
  float: left;
}
.left a{
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.left a:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.left a img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.right{
  border: 5px solid #00008b;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 69%;
  height: 375px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <aside class="left">
  <a><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg"></a>
  <a><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"></a>
  <a><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"></a>
 </aside>
 <section class = "right">
  <h2>Watch your Head </h2>
        <p>This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. </p>
        <p>This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. </p>
        <p>This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. </p>
    </section>
</main>
```